# Pandas for each group of 4 calendar months find the date on which maximum value occured

Tags: pandas, datetime, data-science, pandas-groupby, data-science-experience

For each group of 4 consecutive calendar months Need to find the date on which maximum value occured

My Dataframe looks like this.

[image: DataFrame]

Comment: Expected output: Date on which maximum value occured along with corresponding max value in set of four months

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn as rn
DatetimeIndex =  pd.date_range('1/1/2015', '12/31/2015', freq='B')
np.random.seed(101)
df = pd.DataFrame(rn(len(DatetimeIndex)),index=DatetimeIndex)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='4MS',label='right')).max()[:3]
```

2015-05-01  2.706850
2015-09-01  2.302987
2016-01-01  2.493990

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a new column with a unique value for each group of four consecutive months.
Then sort on this column and on the value, for the later one descending
Then only take group on the column with unique value for 4 consecutive months
Then only take the first element of the group

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime,date

#create a dummy dataframe
values = []
for mo in range(1,13):
    row = {}
    row["date"]=date(2018,mo,1)
    row["val"]=5+0.1*mo
    values.append(row)
df = DataFrame(values)
#create a column which can be ordered and is unique for 
#every group of successive 4 month
#if more than one year is to be considered the lambda function
#should cover this as well
df["quadmester"]=df["date"].apply(lambda x: (x.month-1)/4)
#sort by the added column and then by value
#since the date for which top value in 4 consecutive month
#is considered sort descending on values
df = df.sort_values(by=["quadmester","val"],ascending=[1,0])
#show the dataframe
print df
```

which yields

> ```
>       date  val  quadmester
> ```
>
> 3   2018-04-01  5.4           0
>   2   2018-03-01  5.3           0
>   1   2018-02-01  5.2           0
>   0   2018-01-01  5.1           0
>   7   2018-08-01  5.8           1
>   6   2018-07-01  5.7           1
>   5   2018-06-01  5.6           1
>   4   2018-05-01  5.5           1
>   11  2018-12-01  6.2           2
>   10  2018-11-01  6.1           2
>   9   2018-10-01  6.0           2
>   8   2018-09-01  5.9           2

### | index | date | val | quadmester|

| 0 |3  | 2018-04-01  | 5.4    |  0  |
| 1|     7  | 2018-08-01  | 5.8    |  1  |
| 2|    11  | 2018-12-01  | 6.2    |  2  |

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **groupby** modulo 4 months on date and **agg** with **max** and **idxmax** to get the corresponding max value and its date per 4 consecutive months.

Here is one line solution assuming that date is index as in your example:

`df.groupby(lambda x:(x.year*10 + x.month%4)).agg(['max','idxmax'])`